# Как для select menu  определить картинку

Tags: html

Подскажите пожалуйста как для select menu  определить картинку(вместо стандартной стрелки поставить свою картинку с изображением стрелки)

Comment: Никак.

Comment: Через css никак. Но можете использовать javascript для замены select'а и правильной работы с ним. Варианты решения - в ответах.

Comment: @ling стрелку через `css` очень даже просто. ниже написал пример. а вот сам список, который выпадает при нажатии... да, его без `js` никак не темизировать.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.select {
    border:1px solid #e3e3e3;    
    border-radius:3px;
    color:#616263;
    overflow: hidden; 
    height: 40px;    
    width: 240px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

select{       
    height: 40px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color:#ececec;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 16px;       
    width: 240px;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
.select:after {
    content:"▼";    
    padding: 12px 8px;
    position: absolute; right: 10px; top: 0;    
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;      
    pointer-events: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;   
}
```

```html
<div class="select">
    <select name="select">
        <option>select</option>
        <option>option</option>
        <option>option</option>
        <option>option</option>
        <option>option</option>
        <option>option</option>
        <option>option</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: А давно в FF нормально сделали `-moz-appearance: none`? Некоторое время назад такой фокус не работал.

Comment: Кстати, можно же стрелочку в фон select'а загнать, вместо доподнительного div'а?

Answer (score 0):

Скриптом.
Есть туча готовых плагинов jquery.
Пользую такой: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-selectBox/ — рекомендую, хорошая штука.

Comment: А как его реализовать?

Comment: Ну вообще-то я ссылку дала на страницу плагина :)
И там первой же строкой сказано, как его подключать: $("SELECT").selectBox();
А реализовывать не надо. Его до вас уже реализовали.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery cuSel](http://www.xiper.net/search.html?s=cusel)

Answer (score 0):

Ну еще можно воспользоваться весьма нестандартным способом. Он вряд ли понравится, но работать будет.

Способ заключается в выводе картинки после select`а, а потом сдвижение этой самой картинки в нужную позицию с использованием *CSS-свойства "margin"*

Comment: и z-index))))

Answer (score 0):

- **IE10+**. Псевдоэлемент [-ms-expand](http://htmlbook.ru/css/-ms-expand).
  Остальные это проигнорируют.
- **Webkit**. `-webkit-appearance:none`, padding и background.
  Проверку можно сделать через `@supports`.
- **Остальные**. Кладём `select` в `label`. Делаем select'у отрицательный отступ так, чтобы кусок со стрелочкой не показывался. Приделываем стрелку через ::after или фоном. Минус этого способа в том, что развёрнутый список будет шире поля. Можно пытаться покрыть стрелочку псевдоэлементом, но с этим способом возникли какие-то порблемы и пришлос от него отказаться.

**Итог**. Оборачиваем `select` в `label` и применяем общий способ. Через `@supports` для webkit'ов отменяем лишние изменения и применяем соответствующий способ. Через какой-нибудь css-хак в media проверяем на IE10+ (`@supports` он не умеет), там отменяем лишние изменения, стилизуем `-ms-expand`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать на чистом `CSS`. Если в общих чертах, то нужно спрятать `select` внутри `div`, отключить оформление `select` и темизировать `div` по вкусу.

```css
.select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 298px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
.select-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -9999;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  right: 5px;
  background: url('http://m.cbssports.com/s/store/-1/webapp/cbs/images/dropDown_arrow.png') right center no-repeat;
}
.select-wrapper select {
  width: 298px;
  height: 28px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 7px;
  line-height: 28px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  appearance: none;            /* remove arrow        */
  -webkit-appearance: none;    /* remove arrow Chrome */
  -moz-appearance: none;       /* remove arrow FF     */
}
.select-wrapper select::-ms-expand{
    display: none;             /* remove arrow IE     */
}
```

```html
<div class="select-wrapper">
  <div class="select-arrow"></div>
  <select>
    <option>Test</option>
    <option>Test</option>
    <option>Test</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: а можно вообще без картинок, используя "странное поведение толстого `border`" нарисовать симпатичную стрелку http://codepen.io/Eliseenko/pen/bdarGM